# How to set up a view that show only the log messages related to the node author

Tags: views, rules, status-messages

I'm trying to create a view similar to the Facebook notification that show all the log messages relative **only to the node author**.

I'm working with [message](https://www.drupal.org/project/message) and [rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) and i've already set a view that display all the website activity like: *"user-A likes node-X", "user-A commented node_X"* and so on. But I'm going crazy to set up a view that display only those messages related to the node author so that each author can see only the activities related to its nodes.

Is possible to make this kind of filter?

Comment: So you want to display the view on a user page? Try using a contextual filter filtering the uid of the node. Relationship uid is available for nodes.

Comment: If the only way is on user page... I would like to add a new **link menu** and attach to it a [Drupal Menu Badge](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_badges) counter so when a user go hover this link a sliding block panel will go down. Inside this sliding block i would like to insert my **notification view**.

Comment: Can you explain how to setup this view properly? I'don't have the node uid in my contextual filter... why?

Comment: I do not completely understand the relation of the view to the rest if the page.. Should that view display all nodes authered by the currently logged in user?

Comment: I would like to display all the messages related to the node author: so i.e. if you go on your user page you can see this block with all the users activity related only on your nodes like: "user-x liked your node-y" and so on

Comment: is your view based on content? the contextual filters should contain the author uid. then you choose provide default value if the value does not exist and then you select the entity id from url. the view display should be block.